# How to echo value from an array to textboxes

Tags: php

someone please help me, i cant seem to solve this issue with my code. i have run out of ideas. i need to fill up the dynamic textboxes generate in the while loop with value from the foreach loop, that is from `$doc_list_terminer` to `$listDocPourProjet`.

example: let say we need 3 files from a user. `$listDocPourProjet` will generate 3 textboxes. Lets say, the user has uploaded 2 files. I need to list the 2 files in the first 2 textboxes generated and leave the remaining textbox blank. The 2 files uploaded come from `$doc_list_terminer`.

I get the filenames which are in the variable $nomfichier to echo correctly, i just cant get it in the first 2 textboxes 'docfile' generated by the while loop.

Below is my code:

```
    $iDossiers = 0;
    while($iDossiers < count($listDocPourProjet))
    {
        $icounter = 0;
        foreach($doc_list_terminer as $eachDocTerminer)
        {
            if($eachDocTerminer['DOC_CLIENT_ID']==$listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_ID'])
            {
                $nomfichier = $eachDocTerminer['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC'];
            }

        $icounter++;    
        }
        echo('<br>');

        $nombreDossier = $listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_NUM'];
        $iDos = 0;
        while($iDos < $nombreDossier)
        {
            $counte = $iDos+1;
            echo $iDos;
        ?>              
            <tr>
                <td>
        <?php                   
                    echo $listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_NOM'].' '.$counte;
                    echo "<br>";
        ?>                          

                    <input type="text" id="docfile[<?php echo $listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_ID'].$iDos; ?>]" name="docfile[<?php echo $listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_ID'].$iDos; ?>]" value="<?php echo $nomfichier; ?>" style="width:100%;">

        <?php                       
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        $iDos ++;
        }

    $iDossiers ++;
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
```

thank you.

var_dump(doc_list_terminer) =

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/identite 2.txt
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC_REF] => 
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 1
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_USER_ID] => 2
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_CREATION] => 2019-05-24 15:12:54
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_MAJ] => 2019-05-24 15:12:54
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_STATUT] => 1
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/ identite 3.txt
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC_REF] => 
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 1
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_USER_ID] => 2
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_CREATION] => 2019-05-24 16:55:53
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_MAJ] => 2019-05-24 16:55:53
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_STATUT] => 1
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 701
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/identite 1.txt
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC_REF] => 
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 1
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_USER_ID] => 2
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_CREATION] => 2019-05-24 14:00:41
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_MAJ] => 2019-05-24 14:00:41
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_STATUT] => 1
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Pièce identité
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 101
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/reference bank.txt
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC_REF] => 
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 1
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_USER_ID] => 2
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_CREATION] => 2019-05-22 15:50:06
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_MAJ] => 2019-05-22 15:50:06
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_STATUT] => 1
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Nom de société
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1010
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_ID] => 5701
                    [CLIENT_ID] => 3401
                    [PROJET_ID] => 3901
                    [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC] => upload/doc_client_document/reference bank.txt
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC_REF] => 
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_QTY] => 1
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_USER_ID] => 2
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_CREATION] => 2019-05-22 15:50:06
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_DATE_MAJ] => 2019-05-22 15:50:06
                    [CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_STATUT] => 1
                    [DOC_CLIENT_NOM] => Nom de société
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign `$nomfichier` as an array with `$icounter` index :

```
if($eachDocTerminer['DOC_CLIENT_ID']==$listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_ID'])
{
    $nomfichier[$icounter] = $eachDocTerminer['CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC'];
} else {
    $nomfichier[$icounter] = '';
}
```

And then use `$iDos` as an index on the input, change `echo $nomfichier;` to `echo !empty($nomfichier[$iDos]) ? $nomfichier[$iDos] : '';` :

```
<input type="text" id="docfile[<?php echo $listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_ID'].$iDos; ?>]" name="docfile[<?php echo $listDocPourProjet[$iDossiers]['DOC_CLIENT_ID'].$iDos; ?>]" value="<?php echo !empty($nomfichier[$iDos]) ? $nomfichier[$iDos] : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;">
```

Comment: we are getting very close Dhana. However while some textboxes are filled, i get a notice in some fileds <br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>C:

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer to include a conditional so the rest of the undefined offset input have an empty value

Comment: thanks lol...i did the same thing. However, the first 2 textboxes were suppose to have data in them. for some reasons its not there.... $nomfichier run 2 times in the while loop.

on the 2nd run $nomfichier contains the following:
 Array
(
    [2] => upload/doc_client_document/reference bank1.txt
    [3] => upload/doc_client_document/reference bank2.txt
    [0] => upload/doc_client_document/identite 1.txt
    [1] => upload/doc_client_document/identite 2.txt
)

only textboxes identite 1 and 2 are in the right textbox. Im wondering how to get the reference bank 1, 2 in its textboxes

Comment: I've update my code, I added the `else` conditional so each array should have a value even if empty. Could you try it?

Comment: i tried ur suggestions, the first 2 textboxes are still balnk, now the arrays are as such:


and 2nd run :

Array
(
    [0] => upload/doc_client_document/identite 1.txt
    [1] => upload/doc_client_document/identite 2.txt
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
)

Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => upload/doc_client_document/reference bank1.txt
    [3] => upload/doc_client_document/reference bank2.txt
)

Comment: $doc_list_terminer :

i've repace CLIENT_PROJET_DOC_CLIENT_MODELE_DOC by MODELE_DOC.


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
            [MODELE_DOC] => identite1.txt
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 901
            [MODELE_DOC] => identite2.txt
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
            [MODELE_DOC] => reference1.txt
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [DOC_CLIENT_ID] => 1001
            [MODELE_DOC] => reference2.txt
        )
)

Comment: Any idea Dhana?

Comment: Could you `var_dump($doc_list_terminer);` before the first `while` loop to see what's inside it?